# Автоматическое увеличение значения столбца в MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, у меня есть некая переменная i = 1; как занести значение этой переменной в таблицу PHPMySQL так, чтобы каждый раз значение этой переменной увеличивалось на 1 в таблице. Например - сначала было 1, записываю в БД, затем записываю еще 1, чтобы в таблице было уже 2 и т.д. И вообще возможно так делать?

Comment: что куда вы записываете?

Comment: записываю переменную в БД. только мне нужно чтобы каждый раз эта переменная инкрементировалась на 1 прямо при записе в БД. Может есть какой-либо запрос, чтобы так сделать?

Comment: например, set i = i+1. можно сделать автоинкрементое поле. можно написать триггер на событие обновления/записи в таблицу....задачи нет

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL имеется штатный механизм `AUTO_INCREMENT` для решения этой задачи. Однако, у него имеется ограничение, вы можете снабдить данным атрибутом только один столбец, с уникальным индексом. Как правило, это первичный ключ. Чтобы решить задачу часто прибегают к триггерам - специальным событиям, которые срабатывают до или после выполнения операций `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.

Для определенности пусть имеется таблица `tbl` со столбцом `value`, принимающего целочисленные значения. В этом случае мы можем создать триггер на вставку (`INSERT`), который будет назначать `value` максимальное значение в рамках таблицы, увеличенное на единицу.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `table_increment` BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.`value` = (SELECT MAX(`value`) + 1 FROM tbl);
END//
```

Достаточно вставить в таблицу `tbl` запись со значением вашей переменной в поле `value` и во всех новых вставках (где это значение можно уже не указывать), поле `value` будет автоматически получать следующие значения.

phpMyAdmin допускает выполнения сразу нескольких запросов. Для того, чтобы анализатор мог отделить их от триггера, который в своем составе имеет точки с запятой, нужно изменить признак конца запроса (у нас это //). В phpMyAdmin это можно сделать в поле Разделитель. В консоли для этого предназначена специальная команда `DELIMITER`

```
DELIMITER //
```